# Database having the exact same row of record..Why so?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I have this issue over my DB..There is two row of record with exact same value, which doesn't make sense to me as I tried to insert the exact value using MS SQL Server, the client itself will prompt error --> *'Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'IDX_XXX'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'table XXX'.
The statement has been terminated.'*

So I wanted to know under what circumstances or database design will allow two exact record without having any error.

The data is like below:

```
Column 1    ||  Column 2   ||  Column 3 
---------------------------------------
Ferrari     ||  Rims       ||  Tyre 
---------------------------------------
Ferrari     ||  Rims       ||  Tyre
```

Comment: How do you know the rows are really exactly the same, and don't just look the same?

Comment: Check for extra spaces in one of the key values.

Comment: On second thought that seems unlikely, spaces I mean. Could there be other characters, like spaces but not actually the space character? Or perhaps a special e or a that has a different unicode character?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen hi,i have the extracted data in excel, i have checked it column by column ...not likely. And the insertion of data is by stored procedure, not likely to have issue. Is just his piece of record created 4 years ago left me no clue.

Comment: The chance of SQL Server being right, that there is something different between the two rows is a lot higher than there being a bug in this part of SQL Server. So there is almost certainly something different between the two rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one way that you can check if the data is indeed a duplicate. Drop the constraint, and recreate it. If that is indeed a duplicate, the constraint will not recreate. The changes that there is a difference in the 2 records is very likely, and you might want to go to byte level of the strings and compare each byte of the string.

Chr(13) or a Chr(10) can not be seen in the grid result, and there are quite a number of other characters that cannot be seen either.

I'm not sure if this will actually work, but you can try this:

```
Select convert(varbinary(max), [Column 1]), convert(varbinary(max), [Column 2]), convert(varbinary(max), [Column 3]) where <use your criteria to get the records>
```

This should reveal the HEX for the characters in the string, and you can compare that strings that way

Comment: +1, since the CHAR(10) / CHAR(13) problem is relatively commonplace and produces scenarios exactly like this.

Comment: thanks. it sounds more logical to identify the differences in this way.